# How to create groups in Firebase and then create new users into that group? How do I restrict access to only that group?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-security

I cant wrap my head around How To create a /location/groupID/users/userName with Firebase. Also, how do I restrict each group to only the users inside of that group?

Comment: Please show us some code...

Comment: This seems like a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14491496/.  Have you seen it? Else, please clarify your question.