# Granting access to Firebase locations to groups of users

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How can I grant access to Firebase locations to groups of users?
I found a good solution for only a group of users: [Access to Firebase locations for a group of users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14491496/granting-access-to-firebase-locations-to-a-group-of-users) 
It has the property `group: "group name"` but in my case, it should have a property `groups: [ 'group1', 'group2', ]` or `groups: 'group1, group2, ...'`.   `groups` can be a dictionary object `{'group1': true, 'group2': true}`.

Here is the JSON structure.

```
"Groups": {
  "group1": { "user1": true, "user2": true, ...},
  "group2": { "user3": true,  "user4": true, ... },
  "group3": ...,
  ...
}
"Products": {
   "product1": {
       ...
       "groups": ["group1", "group2"],  "group1 group2" or 
                 {"group1": true, "group2": true} 
   }
}
```

So the users `user1, user2, user3, user4`, members of `group1, group2`  can access the product `product1`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Granting access to Firebase locations to a group of users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14491496/granting-access-to-firebase-locations-to-a-group-of-users)

Comment: It is not the duplicate, there should be a another solution for multi-group access.

Comment: The linked answer shows how to handle groups. There is no better way. The difference with your sample is that you use an array, which is an anti-pattern when it comes to Firebase. One of the many reasons Firebase recommends against using arrays is that it makes the security rules impossible to write. For more see [this blog post](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html) and [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40656589/firebase-query-if-child-of-child-contains-a-value).

Comment: If you're having trouble making the solution in Michael's answer work for your case, edit your question to include the minimal JSON and security rules (as text, no screenshots) and we'll have a look.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I am really looking for a solution for multiple groups for a location, not a single group.

Comment: We really need to see your Firebase structure (TEXT please, no images or links) to generate an answer. The question is a tad vague with out it.

Comment: Thanks for that JSON. I'd recommend doing what everyone by now has recommended and only consider `"group1": true`. Now what rules did you already write? What is the problem with them?

Comment: The problem is I am not sure how to write rules for it looping through the group object in rules.